# array.index(y) not giving expected result in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For some reason prices.index(y) and x are giving me weird answers

```
def stockpicker prices
    profits, buyday, sellday = 0, 0, 0

    i=0
    while i <= prices.length
        y = i + 1
        while y <= prices.length
            if prices[y].to_i - prices[i].to_i > profits
                profits = prices[y].to_i - prices[i].to_i
                sellday = prices.index(y).to_i
                buyday = prices.index(i).to_i
            end
            y += 1
        end
        i += 1
    end

    print "Profits are #{profits} if you buy on #{buyday} and sell on #{sellday}"

end

stockpicker([17,3,6,9,15,8,6,9,1])
```

> =>Profits are 13 if you buy on 8 and sell on 0

why isn't it giving their proper index places? I can't really see where are 8 and 0 come from

Comment: In this case what do you expect the formatted string to be?

Comment: hey, i was going for what Dylan Markow answered. I didn't really understand what .index was giving me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this output:

```
Profits are 12 if you buy on 1 and sell on 4
```

Then you should just set sellday/buyday to the current index values:

```
sellday = y
buyday = i
```

By using `sellday = prices.index(y).to_i`, you're saying "give me the index of the item in the array with the **value** of 4". This results in `nil`. `nil.to_i` will always give you `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your question has been answered, let's see how you can write your code in a more Rubylike way.  There are many ways to do this.  This is one.

**Code**

```
def stockpicker(prices)
  a = Array.new(prices.size) { |i|
        Array.new(prices.size) { |j|
          (j > i) ? prices[j]-prices[i] : -Float::INFINITY } }.flatten
  max_profit = a.max
  bd, sd = a.index(max_profit).divmod(prices.size)
  print "Profits are #{max_profit} if you buy on #{bd} and sell on #{sd}"
end
```

**Example**

```
prices = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,9,1]
stockpicker(prices)
  #=> Profits are 12 if you buy on 1 and sell on 4
```

**Explanation**

For the example given above:

```
a = Array.new(prices.size) { |i|
      Array.new(prices.size) { |j| 
        (j >= i) ? prices[j]-prices[i] : -Float::INFINITY } }
      #=> [[0, -14, -11, -8, -2, -9, -11, -8, -16],
      #    [-Infinity, 0, 3, 6, 12, 5, 3, 6, -2],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, 0, 3, 9, 2, 0, 3, -5],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, 6, -1, -3, 0, -8],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, -7, -9, -6, -14],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, -2, 1, -7],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity,
      #       0, 3, -5],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity,
      #       -Infinity, 0, -8],
      #    [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity,
      #       -Infinity, -Infinity, 0]]
```

The entry in row `i`, column `j` of this array equals the profit if the stock is bought on day offset `i` and sold on day offest `j`.  Consider, for example, row (offset) `1`, which corresponds to stock purchases on day offset `1`:

```
      [-Infinity, 0, 3, 6, 12, 5, 3, 6, -2],
```

Column `j` gives the profit if the stock purchased on day `1` is sold on day offset `j`.  If sold on day 4, for example, the profit is 12.  Note that we assign a profit of negative infinity when the sell day precedes the buy day.

Next, flatten this array:

```
b = a.flatten
  #=> [0, -14, -11, -8, -2, -9, -11, -8, -16,
  #    -Infinity, 0, 3, 6, 12, 5, 3, 6, -2,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, 3, 9, 2, 0, 3, -5,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, 6, -1, -3, 0, -8,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, -7, -9, -6, -14,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0, -2, 1, -7,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, 0,
  #      3, -5,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity,
  #    -Infinity, 0, -8,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity,
  #    -Infinity, -Infinity, 0]
```

Determine the maximum profit:

```
max_profit = b.max
  #=> 12
```

Now we need to find the index of `12` in the flattened array (if there is more than one `12`, obtain the index of the first one):

```
c = b.index(max_profit)
  #=> b.index(12) => 13
```

and then use [Fixnum#divmod](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod) to convert this offset to rows and columns in the unflattened array:

```
bd, sd = c.divmod(prices.size)
  #=> c.divmod(9) => [1, 4] => bd = 1, sd = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using `matrix` manipulation:

```
def stockpicker(prices)
  m = Matrix.build(prices.size){ |x,y| prices[y] - prices[x]}
  max = m.each(:upper).max
  bd,sd = m.index(max, :upper)
  puts "Profits are #{max} if you buy on #{bd} and sell on #{sd}"
end
```

Sample run:

```
prices = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,9,1]
stockpicker(prices)
#=> Profits are 12 if you buy on 1 and sell on 4
```

Explanation:
This builds a square matrix with each price subtracted from each price. Since you only want later days subtracted from earlier days, you only want the upper triangle of the matrix (thus the `:upper`). There are built-in Matrix functions to get the max value and its index.